# Add tag to hotjar recordings via Javascript which is integrated through Tealium

Tags: javascript, tealium, hotjar

So the website that I work on has Hotjar integrated via Tealium(Tealium Customer Data Hub). But now I want to add a tag to hotjar recording via Javascript. The official documentation describes it as :

```
hj('tagRecording', ['iframe']);
```

But hj is undefined. To push events to tealium I usually use `utag.link` but what do I do in case?

Answer (score 0):

I work for Tealium, so hopefully I can help!

I've checked the Hotjar integration code and I'd suggest publishing your new JS snippet as a JavaScript extension in Tealium, scoped to the HotJar tag. This will ensure the `hj` object is present when the code is called.